# Create a new node, for all users of certain role every day

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-rules

I have a content type which I want a node to be created for every active user of a certain role every day.
The node should be "created" by the specific user, so they can go edit it when they login.

I've tried to use the rules module for it, but first of, I cant find a "react on event" that seems efficient.
Secondly, if I just use an event like "Cron maintenance tasks are performed", it doesn't seem that the actions and conditions are able to do what I want.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Share the code you have tried yet.

Comment: Ive created the content type i want to be created and  added a user role, + some users.
Ive installed the rules module.
Ive created a rule event with the "React on event" "Cron maintenance tasks are performed".

Then i want a action where it creates a node for each of these users every day, and set each created node for each user.

So lets say there is 3 users of this role. Then on monday the system should create 3 nodes. Each of these nodes should have their own author which is the 3 users with roles. Then on tuesday it should do the excact same thing, just with 3 new nodes and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a module implementing [hook_cron](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_cron/7). In this hook you would have to get all users, [check if they have a specific role](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/15390/check-if-a-user-has-a-role), and then [create a new node](https://www.drupal.org/node/1388922) for each user.

I do not know any solution which does not involve creating a custom module. Hope it helps.